# Keyboard Extension returns needsInputModeSwitchKey false for UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uikit, ios-keyboard-extension

I have an iOS Keyboard Extension that does not support typing any numbers. Also I have an issue where `needsInputModeSwitchKey` returns `false` for textfields where `keyboardType` is set to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`. Because of that my keyboard doesn't show button for switching keyboards and user cannot switch to system numpad keyboard.

[image]

Is it possible to set somewhere that my keyboard doesn't support number typing? So other apps won't switch to it?